# Quickly add blank lines at specified line numbers using vim?

Tags: vim

I know how to add blank lines above or below the current position of the cursor (using `o` and `O`) but is there a quick way to do add blank lines at arbitrary line numbers? I realize that the original line numbers that I give would no longer be accurate after the first blank line has been added, e.g. if I wanted to add blank lines to line 5, 10, and 15, then after a blank line has been added to line 5, then the second blank line should be added to line 11, and then the third blank line should be added to line 17.

Edit: I can use a macro for this task, i.e `qaO<esc>q`. But then I have to still manually move to the line numbers individually.

Comment: Just a general note: Inserting or removing lines in reverse order (largest line number first) won't screw up the line numbers for the rest of the inserts/deletions.

Comment: if I do this often, I do in shell, it would be much easier than vim. Of course vim can make it for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You simply got `append(lineno, string|list)` which present a few advantages like: it leaves the cursor alone (i.e. where it was), it doesn't mess with any register (but `'[`).

Your specific need is thus solved by:

```
:call map(reverse([5, 10, 15]), 'append(v:val, "")')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general way to add blank lines in **specific** line number without affecting the other lines:

```
:g/^/if (index([5,10,15],line('.')) != -1)| s//\r/g |endif
```

You can add or change the items in the list `[5,10,15]` ( inside the `index()` function ). Those items are the lines which will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use macros.
Let's assume you are in line 5. If you insert a line below, line 10 becomes 11. So, after inserting a new line, move five lines down, assuming that cursor moved to new line. (If the cursor is in line 5 itself, move 6 lines down)

Let's start! 
So, move to line 5. Start recording macro. `qaq` to clear `a` register. Then, press `qa` to start recording. Press `O` to create new line down. Then press `Esc`. Move 5 (or 6 lines) down by pressing `5j` (or `6j`) (I don't remember where the cursor will be. )

Then press `@a` to replay the register recursively. Press `q` to end register. Now, play it by pressing `@a`. This will recursively add a new line and move down 5 (or 6) lines, until last line.

Comment: I don't see how can this be done with macro, say I want to do the change on line# 1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55.... how do you move to the line in macro? OP said he doesn't want to manually moving cursor to target line.

Comment: This doesn't work for "arbitrary line numbers". It works only for the specific example in the post.

Comment: @tnabdb I gave fibonacci line numbers ;-)

Comment: It is possible to do. We can use a variable to increment in Fibonacci order (adding two previous values). Use execute command with the variable storing the Fibonacci value and text motion or movements. Do all these steps while recording macro. ( I have used register and modified its value while recording and playing macro.) If OP can give more info or specific info regarding this, I will change the answer according to that

Comment: imho, this is the best answer if you are doing periodic edits of fixed distances (eg 10, 20, 30, etc...) +1